# Query about calling instance variables in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm calling the following in my application.html.erb view layout

```
<%= @time %>
```

And this is what's in my application controller:

```
def time_now
@time = Time.current
end
```

Yet the time is not displaying on my browser. Any helps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are calling the method `time_now` somewhere in your, say, `index` method?

E.g., try the following in your application controller (and make sure no one is overriding this method in a subclass:

```
def index
  @time = Time.current
end
```

So if your `config/routes.rb` has a `root 'welcome#index'`, make sure the `WelcomeController` does not have an `index` method or is calling `super` so that the `ApplicationController#index` method is called to set `@time`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@time = Time.now
```

But you can also do this in your view, without controller:

```
<%= Time.now %>
```

Comment: `current()` is a Rails specific method added to class `Time`.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely look into the [`content_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) method. This is the tool will help you. As documentation said - *simple content can be passed as a parameter.*

So, simply put inside `application.html.erb` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SamplAdmin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= content_for :time %>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Then pass the content from the view. I passed from `index.html.erb` file as :

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% content_for :time, @time %>
```

Here is the simplified controller :

```
class UsersController < InheritedResources::Base

  def index
    @time = Time.now
  end
end
```